# Why does the statement hold for the sum starting at $n=0$ instead of $n=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05967.pdf), p. 16, line (3.20) which reads

$$
\small
\max\left(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert\rho^n\Vert_2,\varepsilon\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Vert J^n\Vert_2,\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \Delta t\Vert J^n\Vert_2^2\right)^{1/2},\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Delta t\Vert S^n\Vert_2^2\right)^{1/2}\right)\leq C\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}~\tag{3.20}.
$$

It is said, that this is a direct consequence of
$$
\max\left(\sup_{n\geq 0}\Vert f^n\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2,\frac{2}{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Delta t \Vert f^n-\rho^n\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2\right)\leq\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2\tag{3.14}
$$
and the estimates
$$
\Vert\rho^n\Vert_2\leq\Vert f^n\Vert_{2,\gamma}\tag{3.16}
$$
$$
\varepsilon\Vert J^n\Vert\leq (m_2^{\Delta v})^{1/2}\Vert f^n-\rho^n\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}\tag{3.17}
$$
$$
\varepsilon\Vert J^n\Vert_2\leq (m_2^{\Delta v})^{1/2}\Vert f^n\Vert_{2,\gamma},\tag{3.18}
$$
$$
\Vert S^n\Vert_2\leq (m_4^{\Delta v}-(m_2^{\Delta v})^2)^{1/2}\Vert f^n-\rho^n\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}\tag{3.19}.
$$

**But why do the sums in (3.20) start at $n=0$ and not at $n=1$ as in (3.14)?**

If they started at $n=1$ as in (3.14) everything would be clear to me. In this case, $C$ is indeed depending only on uniform bounds on $m_2^{\Delta v}$ and $m_4^{\Delta v}$ as claimed.

---

But if the sums start at $n=0$ this is not clear to me:

If I consider, for instance, the first sum in (3.20), by (3.18) I get

$$
\Delta t\Vert J^0\Vert_2^2\leq \Delta t\frac{m_2^{\Delta v}}{\varepsilon^2}\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2
$$
so that by (3.17) and (3.14),
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Delta t\Vert J^n\Vert_2^2&=\Delta t\Vert J^0\Vert_2^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Delta t\Vert J^n\Vert_2^2\\
&\leq \Delta t\frac{m_2^{\Delta v}}{\varepsilon^2}\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2+\frac{m_2^{\Delta v}}{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Delta t\Vert f^n-\rho^n\mathcal{M}\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2\\
&\leq \Delta t\frac{m_2^{\Delta v}}{\varepsilon^2}\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2+m_2^{\Delta v}\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2\\
&=m_2^{\Delta v}(1+\frac{\Delta t}{\varepsilon^2})\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}^2.
\end{align*}
$$
So if I set $C^2:=m_2^{\Delta v}(1+\frac{\Delta t}{\varepsilon^2})$, I get that
$$
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Delta t\Vert J^n\Vert_2^2\right)^{1/2}\leq C\Vert f^0\Vert_{2,\gamma}.
$$

However, now $C$ depends not only on bounds on $m_2^{\Delta v}$ as is claimed, but also on $\Delta t$ and $\varepsilon$.

Comment: After reading over it, I think this might be a typo. The only place this estimate is used is in the proof of Theorem 1 (page 17), and it doesn't seem like that sum of $J^n$ is even used.